# DRF - Filter from URL instead query Parameters

Tags: django-rest-framework

Lets say I have the following viewset:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
```

I can get all users by hitting the /users/ endpoint of my API.

I also want to be able to list the users of a company by using /companies/{company_id}/users

I want to create a new endpoint, which will reuse my `list` method, but filter the queryset differently.
My idea is to register this route to call another method, lets say `list_by_company`, which will have `company_id` in its kwargs.

How do I register this in the DRF router class?

I'm also welcome to other ideas on how to achieve this filtering, but I do not want to use query parameters as it gets a bit confusing in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can extend the DefaultRouter and add an entry that does exactly what I want:

```
class UserRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    routes = [ 
        routers.Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={'get': 'list'},
            name='{basename}-list',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
        ),  
        routers.Route(
            url=r'^companies/(?P<company_id>[0-9]+)/{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={'get': 'list'},
            name='{basename}-list',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
        ),  
        routers.Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}$',
            mapping={'get': 'retrieve'},
            name='{basename}-detail',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'}
        ),  
    ]
```

However this is a bit verbose since I am rewriting the default routes too.

Then, I can add routers to the DRF routers directly, which is shorter:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.routes.append(
    routers.Route(
        url=r'^companies/(?P<company_id>[0-9]+)/{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
        mapping={'get': 'list'},
        name='{basename}-list',
        initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
    ),
)
```

I am going to use this solution, but I would love to know if other developers are solving cases like this in a different way :)

Comment: Lucas, for me it seems that solution is complicated. Why not to have a different endpoint (viewsets) to represent what you need? DRF's nested routes? I think maintaining code above is very complex, especially by non-original developer of the codebase